# Charts integration in active admin dashboard rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, charts, asset-pipeline

My Dashboard

```
section "Graph", do
div do
    render 'graph'
    end
end
```

_graph.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "charts"
        },
        title: {
            text: "Orders"
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "X axis"
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Y axis"
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [1,3,5,7]
        }]
    });
});
```

In which folder I place that _graph.html.erb so that it can loaded. is JavaScript in it works correctly after that?

Answer (score 6):

Charts integration on active admin is pretty simple, all you have to use is get [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick)  in your Gemfile.

Then in your dashboard.rb you can create another panel within a column and show your graph.
Example:

```
  panel "Top stuff --all name-removed for brevity--" do
        # line_chart   Content.pluck("download").uniq.map { |c| { title: c, data: Content.where(download: c).group_by_day(:updated_at, format: "%B %d, %Y").count }  }, discrete: true
        # column_chart Content.group_by_hour_of_day(:updated_at, format: "%l %P").order(:download).count, {library: {title:'Downloads for all providers'}}
        # column_chart Content.group(:title).order('download DESC').limit(5).sum(:download)
        bar_chart Content.group(:title).order('download DESC').limit(5).sum(:download) ,{library: {title:'Top 5 Downloads'}}
        ##
        # line_chart result.each(:as => :hash) { |item|
        #   {name: item.title, data: item.sum_download.count}
        # }
      end
    end
```

Comment: Wow.  What a great suggestion and great gem.